# Close Opportunity as Lost dialog in Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I require the same functionality in the Partner Portal as in Dynamics CRM.  In Dynamics CRM, when a user close an Opportunity as Lost, a dialog appears to fill in the Description why the opportunity is lost.  I need a similar Dialog on the Partner Portal when the Opportunity is Closes as Lost

Screenshot below is from the Dynamics CRM site:

[image]

Comment: any followup questions?

Comment: Not at the moment.  Still in the process of developing a custom form.

Answer (score 0):

We have to develop a custom form and mimic this functionality on our own, as this is CRM functionality, and not available in portals.

[Similar discussion in Dynamics community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/394502/showing-opportunity-close-form-in-portals):

> When you close an opportunity within CRM, you only see the Opportunity
> close dialog.
>
> The opportunity close form is not used for any CRUD operation, it is
> also tricky to pass opportunity id as it gets modified during the
> process.
>
> I'd recommend using a new custom form which updates the required
> attributes of opportunity Entity and maybe use a Workflow to close the
> opportunity on submit of this form.